# How can I prevent Xcode from finding flat/non-nested imports?

Tags: xcode

This is related to [preserve include path in xcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/913782/preserve-include-path-in-xcode), but is the complimentary problem.

We are organizing our code on disk into logical components with folders like:

```
ComponentA/HeaderA.h
ComponentB/HeaderB.h
```

and require that team members import them like

```
#import "ComponentA/HeaderA.h"
#import "ComponentB/HeaderB.h"
```

We use the USER_HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS pointing at the directory above ComponentA/B to enable the compiler to find these, it works fine.

*However*, these headers are included in the Xcode project, so if someone accidentally uses

```
#import "HeaderA.h"
#import "HeaderB.h"
```

then Xcode will still find the header, but we want it to produce a compiler error. Is there a way to get Xcode to stop finding these headers unless the hierarchical name is used?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [controlling which project header file Xcode will include](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2596695/controlling-which-project-header-file-xcode-will-include)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that this has been asked before in 
[controlling which project header file Xcode will include](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2596695/controlling-which-project-header-file-xcode-will-include)

The key undocumented setting is USE_HEADERMAP=NO, which stops Xcode from automatically finding any header file that has been added to the project.